# SSAS Cube processing failed. returning trace information takes forever

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm using a small c# program to process SSAS databases using the C# API. The problem is that one of the cubes hangs under processing, and `Database.Process()` is a blocking call, meaning that the process hangs until killed through Process Explorer.

If I do the processing manually, through SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following error: `Process failed. Trace information is still being transferred. If you do not want to wait for all of the information to arrive press Stop.` but the behavior is otherwise the same.  After 4 hours, still no trace information. If I press stop it tells me the connection was lost. But if the reason is the connection was lost, how come `Database.Process()` doesn't throw an exception?

I have two questions:

1. How do I start debugging this?
2. Is there some way to programmatically (or otherwise) set a SSAS database to fail-fast without sending a seemingly infinite amount of trace information?

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 if it makes any difference.

Comment: If you process the cube directly in SSAS does it fail?

Comment: Yes. Behavior is identical. I accept that it fails. It's suddenly introduced behavior, so obviously there is an error somewhere. However I would like for my program to handle it elegantly, and just fail the cube processing once the processing has failed, rather than hang for 5+ hours until it gets all the trace information back. Maybe it can't be done. I don't know. Nothing I've found so far on technet indicates that you can, but I'm a noob with SSAS. :(

Comment: I would try to do the SSMS thing and leave it overnight - or over the weekend - to see whether anything comes up in the morning. That would seem to be the best way to get to the data. Failing that, check event logs, and use the profiler as per http://www.bidn.com/blogs/AdamJorgensen/ssas/463/introduction-to-using-profiler-with-ssas-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of debugging Analysis Services issues is using Performance Monitor. You can find this in the start menu at "Microsoft SQL Server 2008/Performance Tools/SQL Server Profiler". Launch this tool, click on "New Trace", select a **Analysis Services** connection, and leave the event selection etc. at their default settings for now, and then click "Run". You will see several events traced of the server to which you connected.

If you then start the processing from your program, you should be able to see this appearing as several events, and hopefully the error will appear in the trace somewhere. Hopefully, you have a server with not too much concurrent actions. Otherwise, you will to have to limit the tracing to specific events before starting it.